# Reference Outlook Account by email address

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have found the following VBA, which I'm using in excel VBA, which will return each Outlook account item and its account number.

```
Sub Which_Account_Number()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim I As Long

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For I = 1 To OutApp.Session.Accounts.Count
        MsgBox OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(I) & " : This is account number " & I
    Next I
End Sub
```

I want to select the account number that is associated to a specific from email address, instead of returning them all one after another.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set it directly

```
Sub Which_Account_Number()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim DesiredAccount As Outlook.Account
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set DesiredAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item("desiredemail@domain.com")
    MsgBox DesiredAccount.DisplayName
    Set DesiredAccount = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Probably [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462091.aspx)  and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863589.aspx) may be helpful as well later on.

Comment: I have tried this but i get: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Figured out what was wrong with it and got that bit working, but I cannot see a property to return the account number? I require the account number to use in '.SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.accounts.Item(4)' replacing the 4 at the end with the appropriate account number on the machine its being run on

Comment: So ive just realised i dont need any of this and can just change the 4 to the email address i want it to set from

Comment: Yes it is stated in the example `.Item("desiredemail@domain.com")`